# VBA code to copy the last cells with data in a certain row

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code to copy the last 26 cells with data of row 10. I have unsuccessfully tried the following code:

```
Sub GetLastCells()
    Dim lc As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PROCV")
         lc = .Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         With .Cells(10, lc - 26).Resize(lr, 27).Copy
    End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to see:

```
Sub GetLastCells()
    Dim lc As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PROCV")
         lc = .Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         kc = lc - 25
         Range(Cells(10, kc), Cells(10, lc)).Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code makes a good starting point, but it seems to copy the last cells not only of row 10, but all subsequent rows.

Comment: Wait a minute, I tried the code again and this time it worked perfectly. Nice.